# Executar javascript na minha extensão do Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, extensão

Fala galera! Trabalho a maior parte do tempo preenchendo formularios web, e muitas das vezes pego cerca de 50-100 páginas com os mesmos dados... Então tenho que preencher manualmente uma a uma.
Tive a ideia de criar uma extensão no Chrome que me permite preencher esses formulários com 1 clique somente. Porém eu também preciso executar o seguinte javascript:

```
javascript: resRecebimentoSelecionado('1', 'Fulano de Souza', 'Gerente');
```

Atualmente minha extenção está

```
var data = document.getElementById("txtDataRecebimento");
data.value = "20/06/2018";

var motorista = document.getElementById("txtTransportadorNomeMotorista");
motorista.value = "Fulano";

var placa = document.getElementById("txtTransportadorPlacaVeiculo");
placa.value = "LLLXXX";

var obs = document.getElementById("txtObservacoes");
obs.value = "N/C";
```

Alguem tem alguma noção de como eu faço pra executar esse Javascript?

Comment: Eu utilizo algumas automatizações simplesmente adicionando um código javascript como favorito na barra de favoritos. Criando uma nova página de favoritos e colocando no link o código, exemplo: javascript: var ok="Ola"; alert(ok); O problema é que vc precisa formatar o código todo em uma linha e fica ruim pra manutenção,

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo algumas automatizações simplesmente adicionando um código javascript como favorito na barra de favoritos.

Criando uma nova página de favoritos e colocando no campo da URL o código.

Exemplo:

```
javascript: var ok="Ola"; alert(ok);
```

Pra utilizar basta clicar no favorito criado que ele executará o código em qualquer página que você esteja.

O único problema é que vc precisa formatar o código todo em uma linha e fica ruim pra manutenção.

Comment: Exatamente... Fica muito ruim! A intenção de criar a extenção no Chrome foi justamente a facilidade pra edição só pelo arquivo .JS, e quem sabe um incremento futuro podendo fazer as alterações pelo própio browser.
Não tem nenhum jeito de executar essa função pela propia extensão? Algum comando que pelo menos de entrada desse JS no console do Chrome

Comment: Amigo estou tentando fazer a mesma coisa que voce, cheguei a criar uma "interface" bonitinha e uma opção "Preencher Form" e ao clicar executaria um código que desenvolvi para os formulários daqui da empresa.Porem esbarrei na política de segurança do google dei uma lida na documentação estou bem perto de conseguir.

Comment: De uma lida nesse link: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/?hl=pt-br